# ExecuteNonQuery doesn't respond?

Tags: c#, oracle

I want to update some columns on my table but `ExecuteNonQuery` doesn't respond (Timeout). Did I do something wrong?

Notes: in the database table, `id` is integer, `F1` varchar2 and the parameters I am sending are string and int.

```
try {
    using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(ConString)) {
                con.Open();

                OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
                cmd.Connection = con;

                cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE DB.Table "+
                                  "SET F1= :yd" +
                                  "WHERE ID = :id";

                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                cmd.Parameters.Add("yd", yd);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("id", id);


                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                con.Close();
                return true;
    }
}
catch (Exception ex) {
    return false;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What is your column types? What are your parameter values? You get any exception or error message?

Comment: F1 is string and id is int.

Comment: Looks like that the problem is not in the query and in the code. I delete my answer because there is no value in it, probably you should check the last assumption of codemonkey.

Comment: A typo? There is no space between the `:yd` parameter and the following `WHERE`

Comment: @Steve I think that this is possible to be the problem too, but I wrote my answer with space between them and he said that the error is the same. And this will not throw a timeout exception.

Comment: @mybirthname that's why I think is a typo. Also an error message should be given in that case. I would also ask the OP to remove the try/catch block. Using a try/catch without doing nothing with the exception is the perfect recipe for misterious bugs. Remove it and let the exception show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that is because of other program like toad locks the query. After commiting all thing in toad, everything is solved.

Thanks for all for helping. I love you guys, i like brainstorming :)

Answer (score 1):

It can be solved by **committing or roll backing pending transactions** on your Oracle developer or any other ***IDEs running on your machine***.

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing up your parameter names. There is no parameter named "F1" in your query, use "yd".

```
            cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE DB.Table "+
                              "SET F1= :yd" +
                              "WHERE ID = :id";

            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            cmd.Parameters.Add("yd", yd);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("id", id);
```

Comment: I fixed still doesnt response?

Comment: no exception, i cannot debug after executenonquery() line. Still waits for response.

Comment: Locked resource and your program waits for timeout/idefinite?

Comment: Yep it waits for timeout, i didnt find why didnt execute this code?

Comment: The fact that it's waiting for the timeout indicates the problem is not your query but either a locked resource (some onther program has an outstanding transaction that locked the record you want to update) or a very large update (is the id field the primary key?). I'd go for the lock by other program.

Comment: Id key is primary key. It doesnt throw any error, even timeout. I didnt understand that act.

Comment: @codemonkey the problem is because of other requests wait in toad. After clicking commit, everthing is solved. Thanks for help.

Answer (score -1):

```
            cmd.Connection = con;

       string qry = "UPDATE DB.Table "+"SET F1= @yd" +"WHERE ID = @id";

        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(qry,con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@yd", yd);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: How did you use cmd? two times?